# Simplest way to compile an autotools based shared C library for Android?

Tags: android, autotools, shared-libraries

I have a cross-platform C library that I need to compile for Android as a *.so file. The library consist of many .c and .h files, and it use autotools as it's buid system. (./configure && make dep && make). Afaik, the library does not depend on other libraries, other than libc and OpenSSL (which should be present on Andriod).

I'm trying to find the simplest (read fastest in terms or not needing to read hundreds of pages of manuals and then apply try && fail brute-force approaches to complete the task) way of getting the library off my machine in source code form, and into the Android phones as a .so. The library will eventually be accessed from Java's native library interface. For development, I have both Windows and Debian machines on my desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up manually creating an Android NDK project with all the required files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky and the autotooled project is set up correctly, you can cross-compile by running (this example is cross-compiling for windows using mingw, I do not know what the prefix is for Android):

```
./configure --host=i586-pc-mingw32
```

This will then try to find compilers with a prefix of `i586-pc-mingw32-`, so `i586-pc-mingw32-gcc` will likely be the first one found and used. For your Android devkit, have a look at what your compiler binary is called and guess the host value from that.